# How to automatically accept request without asking confirmation in metamask wallet

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

[image]

When I send a request from a Decentralized Application I don't want to appear metamask popup every time.

Please help me how can I avoid metamask popup every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get confirmation every time you spend ethereum / gas.

The only way you won't get that confirmation is when you call a contract method marked as view using call() instead of send().

In this case the wallet will compute locally the result since there is no need to modify anything in the blockchain.

Comment: Can you please share a link to the contract methods and the types?